# SDL and Dynamic Super Resolution?

Tags: opengl, sdl

Is there a way to do DSR with SDL and OpenGL?  As far as I know this is an NVidia thing (I have an NVidia card), so would this be something done in a shader?  I can't find anything in the SDL reference and some googling around doesn't reveal anything either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the top of my head, the best way to do that would be using framebuffers. 
You do your rendering on a larger FBO ([FBO Documentation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object)) than your screen resolution, then you downsample your FBO to another framebuffer that fit the size of the screen using a pixel shader. 
This is OpenGL-specific, so you should be able to do it on SDL.

The [OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples#Quick_example.2C_render_to_texture_.282D.29) has some snippet of code to render to FBO, it should be useful to get you started. And since what you wanna do is basicly downsampling, you might be interested in [this thread](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/176053-downsampling-texture-using-FBO).